# Create an animated GIF to demo an Android app

Tags: android

What is the best way to create an animated GIF to demo an Android app like this one?

[image]

I thought of creating a series of snapshots and then stitch them into a GIF, but that would not show the activity transitions as in the sample above.

Also, the 'screen record' feature in the Android emulator does not capture the device frame.

Other thoughts?

Comment: Record a screencast, then convert the resulting MP4 to a GIF.

Comment: @CommonsWare Look at the device frame and the shadow at the bottom. I don't think this was made by simply recording the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the device frame portion of your request.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using emulator you can follow below steps to record GIFs directly (without need of conversion from mp4 to gif etc)

- Click `...` option placed at bottom of your emulator's option menu bar (one with option to change device orientation and many more)
- In subsequent screen you'll see many advance options from which you have to select `Record and playback`
- Click on `Record Again` option to start the recording (record whatever you want in demo)
- Once you're done click on `Stop recording` this will give on to save the video where by default `WEBM` is selected. Click on dropdown and choose `GIF` and save the video.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Motorola device running Android 12 or higher (e.g. Moto G62), you can use the "GIF maker" Quick Settings tile:

[image: Quick Settings screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

On the emulator window, click on the 3-dots menu and you will find the option to record and Save as GIF, see the screenshot

[image: emulator window]